# Apply Difference-in-Differences to Pre Cost Comparison

Tags: difference-in-difference, pre-post-comparison

**Context:**
There are two groups of users ('Control' and Test') that are randomly assigned at the beginning. (Let's assume they finished allocation right before week 0 and not accepting new users and allocation process is within minutes)

**Description:**
From week 0 to week 6, we do nothing on 'Control' and apply 30% off for 'Test' group
From week 7 to week 12, 'Control' remains the same, we applied 20% off instead for 'Test' group (users saw 30% off before have the chance to see 20% off after)
We'd like to measure the differences in sales for 'Test' group when applying 30% off vs. 20% off.

**Question:**
I'm trying to see if can apply 'Differences in Differences' to mitigate 'Time' effect? (It exists as we used 'Control' group to do a pre and post comparison and result is stats sig different)

**Thought Process:**
For this pre-post comparison following traditional 'DID' structure: 'Treatment' has value 1 or 2 (30% off, or 20% off) for 'Test' and value 0 for 'Control'; 'Time' has value 1 for 'Post-Period' and value 0 for 'Pre-Period'; 'DID' will be 'Time' * 'Treatment' (either 0 or 2).

| Test Group | Time Period | User | Time | Treatment | DID (Time*Treatment) | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Control | Week 0~6 | a | 0 | 0 | 0 | x1 |
| Test | Week 0~6 | b | 0 | 1 | 0 | x2 |
| Control | Week 7~12 | a | 1 | 0 | 0 | x3 |
| Test | Week 7~12 | b | 1 | 2 | 2 | x4 |

Since the goal is to compare within 'Test' group on '30% off' vs. '20% off'. If we do a similar linear regression on: Sales ~ Time + Treatment + Time*Treatment in the following example. My thought is we cannot get what we need? But want to confirm with this group.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yeah just shortened the description hope more readable now (goal is to see if we can apply 'DID' for this type of comparison?)

Answer (score 0):

If you lack data from weeks where control and treatment had the same experience (say no discount in weeks -6 to 0), then I would regress sales on:

1. a constant
2. in_weeks_0_6 X ever_treated interaction
3. in_weeks_7_12 X ever_treated interaction
4. in_weeks_7_12

The coefficient on (1) gives you the mean outcome for 0% off in the 30% off period.

The coefficient on (2) gives you the effect of 30% off vs 0% off.

The coefficient on (3) gives you the effect of 20% off vs 0% off.

The coefficient on (4) gives you the difference in sales between getting 0% off in the first period vs 0% off in the second period.

Cluster your SEs by user since the same person can appear multiple times in your data.

This is not DID; it is the usual T vs C comparison that allows the treatment effect to vary by discount period. You don't need DID here since randomization ensures that the two groups are comparable and there are no pre-existing differences.

Given your conjecture, you would test the null that the two interaction coefficients are equal. You could also do a one-sided test where the null is in_weeks_0_6 X ever_treated interaction <= in_weeks_7_12 X ever_treated interaction versus the alternative that in_weeks_0_6 X ever_treated interaction > in_weeks_7_12 X ever_treated interaction coefficient.

This assumes no interference/substitution across time, which is unlikely to hold with durable or storable goods. One way that this can be violated is that the customers who were persuaded by the 30% off promotion would also have bought had it been 20% off, but because you ran the bigger discount first, the response in the second period was more muted since you already harvested some of that demand.

Comment: Thank you dimitriy, you are right we don't have that (weeks -6~0 no discount) following your point, can we just use data from 'Test' group and do a regression on: sales ~ treatment_1 (week 0~6) + treatment_2 (week 7~12). Curious how do we handle 'Time' effect in this case (mentioned that as we know the behavior is different in two period. Thank you!

Comment: No, you need the control observations in the model to serve as the baseline. You can put in a time dummy for the second period, but that won’t handle my concern. It will just pick up any effects shared by the two groups, like seasonality.

Comment: Gotcha, would that be a regression on sales ~ treatment_1 (week 0~6) + treatment_2 (week 7~12) + Time + treatment_1 * Time (value will be 0 as Time is 0) + treatment_2 + Time (value 1) ? If so, which variable shall we refer to in the report? Thanks!

Comment: @CrubalChenxiLi I am not sure I fully understand your notation. I edited the post to make things clearer.

Comment: Thank you for updating the post! I guess the gap is from 'This assumes no interference/substitution across time' --- as there is stats sig difference on 'Pre' and 'Post' periods for 'Control' and think that would affect 'Test' group as well that users that didn't accept 30% off before may affect 20% off offer later on. In that scenario, can we do a regression on: (sales) Y ~ constant + in_weeks_0_6 X ever_treated interaction + in_weeks_7_12 X ever_treated interaction + in_weeks_7_12 + in_weeks_7_12 * in_weeks_7_12 X ever_treated interaction ?

Comment: That SS does not mean there is necessarily substitution. It could just mean that sales are different in the second period because of seasonality. Your model won't run because of collinearity since n_weeks_7_12 X ever_treated interaction  =  in_weeks_7_12 * in_weeks_7_12 X ever_treated interaction  since 1*1=1.

Comment: Yeah you're right, adding 'in_weeks_7_12 * in_weeks_7_12 X ever_treated interaction' will not help. Guess as you mentioned earlier in the post, maybe we cannot use this approach because the hypothesis of 'no interference/substitution across time' doesn't stay?

Comment: @CrubalChenxiLi, Can you elaborate on what triggers the randomization and notification of the discount? You can edit your question with that info rather than doing it here. For example, do you split customers into two groups by hashing their IDs and then send them a message announcing a discount at the beginning of each period? If you have some new users that trickle into the experiment, you might be able to do some auxiliary analysis. For example, a user who enters the sample in 20% off weeks may not be aware of the 30% discount.

Comment: Sure just updated the description hope that makes more sense.